# bash loop file in one folder against all files in another folder

Tags: for-loop, unix, intersect, bedtools

I am trying to do a ([bedtools](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html)) intersect. Anyone see what is wrong with my bash code here?

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$(pwd)
query=$dir/query_beds
pgs=$dir/pgs_beds

for file in $query/*; do 
   bedtools intersect -wa -wb -a $file -b $pgs/* -c -C -sorted -filenames
done > ${file%.*}-results.txt
```

"query" directory contains many files which need to each be iteratively queried against many files in "pgs" directory using the package bedtools and command intersect, which allows an asterisk for file "-b" to cycle multiple files.

Per usage:

```
One or more BAM/BED/GFF/VCF file(s) “B”. Use “stdin” if passing B with a UNIX pipe.
NEW!!!: -b may be followed with multiple databases and/or wildcard (*) character(s).
```

I believe the problem is with $pgs/*, looping one file against multiple files in another directory and I may need to restructure my loop to change directory or something.

UPDATE:

I have updated the script to work and was able to get everything working with:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
dir=$(pwd)
query=$dir/query_beds
pgs=$dir/pgs_beds
for f in $(ls $query/*.bed); do 
   for g in $(ls $pgs/*); do
      bedtools intersect -wa -wb -a $f -b $g* -C -filenames
   done > $(basename $f .ext).txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code the output of the whole loop is redirected to one file. Maybe you want something like below (redirect the output of each bedtool to a separate file).

Also note that if you use `${file%.*}` the outputs will be created in the `$query` directory so executing the script twice might result in unexpected results. I would recommend to use `$(basename $file .ext).txt` (where .ext is the extension of the files in `$query`. The basename command keeps only the name of the file (so without the directory) and also removes the .ext if present.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$(pwd)
query=$dir/query_beds
pgs=$dir/pgs_beds

for file in $query/*; do 
   bedtools intersect -wa -wb -a $file -b $pgs/* -c -C -sorted -filenames > ${file%.*}-results.txt
done
```

Comment: While that is good information, the resulting error is not with the output file. I'm getting:
"command not found 7: 
/*. Exiting.e to open file /Users/clemaster/.."

Comment: I would recommend using "#!/bin/bash -x" on the first line of the file. This should show you all commands executed. Also, what version of bash are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.2.57. 

I've added both your suggested alternative output method and -x to the first line, neither seems to produce a different result.

Comment: Bash 3.2 is from 2006 see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell). That's very old! As I have no access to such an old version (mine is 5.1), I can't help. I would recommend you to somehow update bash or use a system with a newer version.

Comment: I am now using version 5.2. It still yields the same error. A Biostars user thinks the for loop needs to contain a second for loop, one for each directory, and should use $(ls $query/*.bed) instead. I'll be sure to update here if there is any resolution.

Comment: Another suggestions: if you try to execute "bedtools" in the same folder does it work? Command not found could suggest that bedtools is not found. If I run the script: `for F in local_dir/*; do echo $F/*; done` for me works as expected...

Comment: Bedtools was in the path. I did find that \r was showing up in the path when I started fixing the issue, which is a result from writing the script on my PC and running it on my mac. Heads up that the dos2unix package will clear up those issues. It turns out I needed to nest a loop within a loop.

My resulting script that works has been added to the original post. Thanks for your time and help!